# How to display literal strings in SQL query results?

Tags: sql

This might be a simple problem. i would like to add special characters to my concatenated column when i display it. This the query that I have:-

```
select emp"EMP",concat(INITCAP(lastname), 
       INITCAP (firstname))”Full name”,
       INITCAP (goals)”Goals” from employeesTHREE ORDER BY lastname;
```

result needed:-

```
EMP     Fullname                       Goals
___________________________________________

1       thomas,mathew ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ To be the best
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do something like this...

```
concat(concat(INITCAP(lastname), INITCAP (firstname)), '~~~~~')
```

Comment: that is the correct answer , i will give u the points. But how do i get the comma between the last and first name. Concatenation just concatenates the words as in - thomasmathew and not thomas,mathew

Comment: Concat(INITCAP(lastname),',',INITCAP(firstname)) can be used. And for you to get a better understanding on [literal strings](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/literal-character-strings.php) look at the embedded link :-)